# Are questions about a slightly adult SciFi comic acceptable?

Tags: discussion, scope, adult-content

The specific webcomic series in question is http://rosalarian.com/lesbianpirates/?p=2143 ("I Was Kidnapped By Lesbian Pirates From Outer Space!!!")

Are the questions about it acceptable? (provided the questions center around SFF content and not the fairly-rare NSFW non-SciFi content).

Comment: No idea whether the downvotes mean “no, these questions are not acceptable” or “of course they are, don't waste our time”.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure. Do not link to outright porn, because that triggers some nanny web filters. IWKBLPFOS isn't particularly “adult” (it has less nakedness than [YAFGC](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yafgc)) anyway. Warn people if you're linking to [NSFW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nost_safe_for_work) content. Avoid including “racy” panels in your post. Beyond that, it's SF, so it's on-topic.

Related: [Are adult movies (as far as industry, actors, etc… are concerned) on topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/are-adult-movies-as-far-as-industry-actors-etc-are-concerned-on-topic) on [Movies & TV Stack Exchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) (answer: yes).