# Is Jacqueline Carey's "Kushiel's Legacy" series in scope?

Tags: discussion, scope, adult-content

Is Jacqueline Carey's "[Kushiel's Legacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kushiel%27s_Legacy)" series in scope?

1. Is there consensus that it is "Fantasy"? Wiki says "historical fantasy or alternate history" in the series page, and "Fantasy" in the first book of the series.

   I would personally easily classify it as "Fantasy":

   - leaving aside literary analysis, it's published by **Tor books** :)
   - Heck, the first novel in the series won a [Locus Award](http://www.locusmag.com/SFAwards/Db/Locus.html) in Fantasy category.

   But would like a second opinion, preferably from someone familiar with the works if possible, since I have seen people classify the books as more of a soft-core BDSM porn than fantasy.
2. Is there a concern about allowing questions **about a work** that is, in large part, "adult themed" (heavy BDSM references+erotica)? [ assume that the questions themselves are PG13 or whatever the official cutoff is for SFF.SE ]

   The reason for the concern is that, AFAIR, Stack has canceled Area 51 proposal of exuality due to concerns about brand damage (don't recall exact details). If any work will raise the concerns, Carey's would be it.

Comment: I am pretty sure the consensus on #2 will be "yes" based on [Meta1](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1582/whats-our-tolerance-for-adult-content) and [Meta2](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1885/are-questions-about-a-slightly-adult-scifi-comic-acceptable).

Comment: Unless you add explicit pictures/descriptions to your posts, I'm pretty sure nobody sane would complain.

Comment: @bitmask - there are plenty of things prohibited on SE network that I would classify as "nobody sane would complain" :)

Comment: *Ahem*. If it is BDSM then suffice it to say, it is probably *someone's* fantasy. I am inclined to disallow it though, so that another book with varying levels of a particular monotone chromatic tint doesn't make it on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [Are works that aren't SF per se, but have occasional SFnal elements on-topic? (e.g. spy movies)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-works-that-arent-sf-per-se-but-have-occasional-sfnal-elements-on-topic-e) (and other discussions with a similar outcome), if it's borderline SF, it's in. I haven't read any of the *Kushiel* series, but based on the Wikipedia description, it's firmly on-topic, not even borderline, since it is based on a [fantastical premise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elua_and_His_Companions) (and even if the premise was mundane, it would be on-topic as alternate history).

I don't see any concern with “adult themes” (or as adults call it, sexuality). The main constraint in this respect is to keep images PG-13, which [is a concern for comics](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1885/are-questions-about-a-slightly-adult-scifi-comic-acceptable) but not for written works. The problem with the cancelled sexuality site was a lack of quality, not the theme (the proposal was allowed to go through, the site failed in private beta).

Comment: "based on a fantastical premise" - the premise is... I'd call it "theological". Forgot to add that to the Q as one of my points of concern. +1 for the meta lik

Comment: As far as sexuality site, I though someone (one of the mods) mentioned that there were some meta-concerns not related to site quality. I'm a bit hazy on which site the comment was on, I think History or Skeptics, so I may be mis-remembering

Comment: @DVK I didn't participate on the Sexuality site, so you may be better-informed. In the previous threads that you cited in a comment, there were links to [an official answer](http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/102/lets-talk-about-sex/109#109) stating that sex is not a taboo topic, and (as you well know) [adult movies can be discussed on Movies.SE](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/263). As for the theological part… that's not a reason to exclude a work: it's a fictional religion, so what?

Comment: IIRC we have had a couple of disputed questions touching on theology. So I figured it's better to check.

Comment: @DVK: there were a *lot* of concerns over the subject matter and how it reflects on the network, looks to automated web filters, causes problems for users who want associated accounts, etc. However, we tried to launch it anyway. After a week in private beta, it was in a sorry state - only 58 questions posted, 8 of them closed, and the general feeling of a not-very-active discussion board rather than a Q&A site. That being said, [sexually explicit material is explicitly disallowed by our content policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy) - so keep it as clean as possible.

Comment: @Shog9 - Thank you. As note in the Q, the concern was with the themes of the work, not the questions (since the explicit material in it has no SFF value or angle)