# Is there an age limit on this site?

Tags: discussion, users

I just ran into an answer where the user said they were 9 years old.  This got me wondering about the age limit for the site.

Is there one?  **Do we have an official or unofficial minimum age before someone is allowed to participate on the site?**

---

I realize that age is not a required field when signing up so there is no real way to enforce anything.  I'm just curious if most people think that everyone on the site should be at least *x* years old, or if the thought is that as long as a person is capable of using the site they are welcome here.

Comment: 42. The answer is **always** 42.

Comment: @DVK Conveniently you list your age as 42. You're underage aren't you?

Comment: @Null - *\*whistling innocently\**

Comment: Never mind, found it.

Comment: Whew! Saw your title and was afraid you were talking about a **maximum** age!

Comment: See also: [According to the ToS, are children younger than 13 allowed to read network content? If not, why?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188162/according-to-the-tos-are-children-younger-than-13-allowed-to-read-network-conte)

Comment: And if you have enough rep to see deleted questions, there was some related discussion [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/3047/5184).

Answer (score 22):

Per my answer [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5033/20774), the [Stack Exchange Legal Policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal) explicitly states...

> *Subscriber* certifies to Stack Exchange that Subscriber is an
>   individual (i.e., not a corporate entity) **at least 13 years of age.** No
>   one under the age of 13 may provide any personal information to or on
>   Stack Exchange (including, for example, a name, address, telephone
>   number or email address).

Comment: So Subscriber is allowed to post, so long as they don't share identifying information?

Comment: @asteri - No. In order to post, you need to create an account. By definition, even if the account-holder provides fake info, they're still underage.

Comment: @asteri - The same legal mumbo-jumbo then goes on to say *"Subscriber also certifies that they are legally permitted to use the Services and access the Network, and takes full responsibility for the selection and use of the Services and access of the Network. This Agreement is void where prohibited by law, and the right to access the Network is revoked in such jurisdictions."*. 'Accessing services' seems to includes reading the site's content. So under-13s shouldn't be reading the site either

Comment: That's amazing.

Comment: But it neither explicitly states 12 and under are banned, and it continues by ONLY restricting what those under 13 may NOT PROVIDE to be personal information. Contradictory statements.

Comment: @cde - It says that under 13's shouldn't be using the services. That includes reading the site's content. And yes, I do appreciate that there's no registration required to *actually* do so, but the legalese still applies regardless.

Comment: Then why is the distinction made on providing *personal* information as to opposed to *any* or non-disclaimed information?

Comment: @cde - Do I look like a lawyer? Go ask Jeff Atwood :-)

Comment: So, by using the site they agree to the contract. But in many US states & other countries, a person that age can't be bound by a contract. But a 9-year-old is using the site. Which means that he/she agreed to the contract when creating their account. But a person that age can't agree to a contract. But they're using the site. AAAAAGGGGHHHH.

Comment: @Omegacron - I think the idea is to try to cover your a*se as much as is possible. Although it's not legally binding in most places, the fact that it's legally binding anywhere is sufficient to put it on the site. If you get sued 100 times, it's better to be covered once than not at all.

Comment: @Richard - I agree. We'll just accept that contracts are wibbly wobbly and move on.

Comment: @Omegacron - And only between Ferengi.

Answer (score 15):

There is an age limit, no one under 13 is allowed on the site (you can thank [coppa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children%27s_Online_Privacy_Protection_Act) for that). If you see evidence someone is under 13, please flag for moderator attention with a custom reason saying so.

Comment: Just to be sure, does this also apply to a person under 13 from a country where COPPA does not apply (i.e. not the States)? I suspect it has to do with the servers being located in the US, right?

Comment: SE's rule about no one under 13 certainly applies. I'm not sure whether coppa explicitly applies to them directly or if they're just incidental since it's basically impossible for SE to know whether coppa applies.