# What are the decency standards on stack exchange?

Tags: discussion, scope, adult-content

I have a particular question that I want to post that deals with somewhat unpleasant concepts.  I do not want to rustle any feathers or step on any toes (I learnt my lesson from my question about gender non-conforming magical people in the Potterverse).

So I want to ask here and get a better understanding of what is and is not appropriate.  What topics, if any, are considered taboo on the Sci-Fi and Fantasy Stack Exchange?

Comment: Considering we're dealing with fantasy I would say there is no strict taboo as it is fantastical. Anything goes. As long as there's no intention of harming anyone, there's no issue with it.

Comment: Okay, so for the sake of example, if there was a story in which there is a strong implication of rape, and I want to ask if that is accidental or intentional, that would not be a problem?

Comment: Yep, we've had such questions. [Here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161646/did-sebastian-sexually-assault-his-female-neighbor) is the most recent one I can recall

Comment: As long as it isn't about HP or The Flash, you should be fine.

Comment: Damn.  It is about HP.  The trouble is now I cannot tell if you are messing with me or not ibid.

Comment: It's probably fine. We just had a flood of horrible 'did X rape X in HP' at one point, that's all he's referring to.

Comment: I can see why that would be annoying.  I shall check the questions out and see if it's worth asking mine.

Comment: You won't  be able to the view the questions as they've since been deleted, but [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10317/why-were-these-questions-about-sexual-assault-in-the-harry-potter-franchise-dele) was a meta post about it.

Comment: See [What's our tolerance for adult content?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1582/70236) and [Is there an age limit on this site?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5284/70236) The overall consensus is that we strive to be PG-13-compatible, and if you want to add "adult" content, you might want to use neutral language and some spoiler formatting (and maybe a disclaimer, if you feel like it).

Comment: This is an interesting question and to a point can be subjective. Also be mindful of keywords that may trip [Smoke Detector](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/5072/smokedetector) in [charcoal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) - these keywords can be tweaked for differing sites.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Why should tripping SmokeDetector be an issue? If the post itself isn't offensive, the Charcoal crew can always tell Smokey it was a false positive and no harm done.

Comment: @Randal'Thor only if there were regular keywords that were being used, and also the crew there would need to know what your site thinks is acceptable. As there's different standards for different sites, due to the content. I'm sure you're aware of this

Comment: As well as the questions linked by @Gallifreyan, see also [Does this question comply with the site's policy regarding explicit content?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5031/31394) and [Should questions about sex and other adult activities be off-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3043/31394) Unsurprisingly, this issue has come up a *lot* before.

Comment: [Here is a somewhat relevant question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158615/why-didnt-draco-do-anything-to-hermione-after-she-punched-him-in-the-face) that has not been deleted. The other two such questions ([this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144396/did-draco-malfoy-rape-hermione-granger) and its dupe, both deleted) are two-line questions that can be summed up as "I heard Draco raped Hermione, is it true?". Oh, and we also had a question about Bellatrix raping Hermione, but I can't find that one yet.

Comment: Further to @Gallifreyan's comments, I would note that when "indecent" questions have been deleted, it's usually been by mod intervention and due to more issues than just the content of the questions. If there's no reason to believe you're asking in bad faith (the fact that you're thoughtful enough to make this meta post first speaks volumes in itself), then you're unlikely to be penalised for posting questions on delicate topics. There are some nice guidelines [on another meta](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/165/17) about how to minimise offence/shock when asking such a question.